# How to make headers bold in alasql export to xlsx

Tags: javascript, alasql

I am exporting an array to xls using alasql.
It seems header:true or header:false has no effect on showing or not showing the headers. In my case I want to show the headers, but I want them to be bold.
This is what I am using, but it is not working. Can you give me some advice please?

```
data = [{enddata : "2016-07-12", lc-type : "Ingredient", order :"2057207"}, {enddata : "2016-07-12", lc-type : "Ingredient", order :"2057208"}];

var opts = [{sheetid:'LCList',header:true, column: {style:{Font:{Bold:"1"}}}}];
        var res = alasql('SELECT INTO XLSX("LCList.xlsx",?) FROM ?',[opts,[data]]);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Your `header:true` should be `headers:true`
2. Please avoid having the options in an array (`[` and `]`)
3. See working example of bold headers here: http://jsfiddle.net/78cdxfww/

Comment: The headers:true are working now :) I put the options in an array because in my example I also have multiple sheets, and each sheet has it's own options. I can not get the headers to  be bold like in the jsfiddle example.

Comment: I think after opening the xls, it is trying to modify the layout, but has not enough permissions to do so...... I get error : run-time error '70': Permission denied.

Comment: So the file from the fsfiddle does not have bold headers when you open?

Comment: in the jsfiddle example it has bold headers, and also no run-time error...

Comment: Then I suggest taking the example and shape it until it reflects your needs.

Comment: @mathiasrw When saving as .xlsx file extension we don't see any styles getting applied. Is it a know issue or am I missing something?